# Does this kitchen faucet fit with this sink?

Tags: faucet, installation, kitchen-sink, soap-dispenser

I bought a kitchen sink and kitchen faucet. (Links are in a text file at this location because I'm not allowed to post more than 2 links.)
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zq4kbe5baavaodb/AAB_TZ5vBKzEgJWsXzRUUDG5a?dl=0

I've also included 3 pictures of my current sink and faucet I want to replace and the piping underneath.

The kitchen faucet I bought has a separate soap dispenser and I presume it requires a separate hole in the sink.

The sink I bought has 3 holes and I presume that 1 is for the main faucet and the other 2 are for the hot and cold water.

Does this mean I have to drill a hole in this sink if I want to install the soap dispenser?

Or do I have to buy a sink that accommodates a separate soap dispenser?

Comment: You don't have any reputation here, therefore the site doesn't trust you enough to post more than two links.  For the same reason, most folks aren't going to click on a dropbox link. If you post the photos on Imgur, and then put the Imgur links in a comment, somebody will edit them into the question.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest option in my opinion is to get a sink with a 4th hole cutout for the soap dispenser if you want that. They are a fairly standard option when searching for sinks and I think the resulting look is the best.

It may be possible to drill another hole, but I wouldn't recommend it. If you attempt this, please use a center punch to make a dent to start the hole saw in, otherwise the bit will slide all over the sink and not where you want to drill. The reason I wouldn't consider it is the high risk of damaging the finish and possibly making the hole in the wrong place.

If you don't like the first two options, you can only use one hole in the sink for most modern faucets. They typically include an option to install a cover plate to hide the other two holes. If you don't use that plate, you have two holes to use for soap and lotion dispensers.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see any sinks with a separate hole for the soap, but, I'll look again. I noticed checking the various options using the website doesn't always filter the results properly.

Answer (score 1):

The use of the base plate (escutcheon) for this faucet is **optional**. You do not need to drill an additional hole or buy a different sink. You really only need two of the three holes if you use the soap/lotion dispenser.

See this: [installation manual](https://www.moen.com/shared/docs/instruction-sheets/ins10205a.pdf)

You end up with the faucet in one hole, the soap dispenser in one hole, and covering the unused 3rd hole with a sink hole cover, like in this picture:

[image]

The hole covers come in practically any finish:

[image]